Need to load data into Target table with name mismatching
I am working with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and have a challenge involving dynamic data loading into a SQL database using Azure Data Factory's Copy Activity. Here is the situation:
Files in ADLS Gen2:

DESCRIPTION_CANDIDATENOTES_20231026.txt
DC_RESUMEPDFs_20231026.txt
DESCRIPTION_Job_Index_20231026.txt

Corresponding Target SQL Table Names:

DESCRIPTION_CANDIDATENOTES
DESCRIPTION_RESUME
DESCRIPTION_JOB

For the Copy Activity, I have parameterized the table name and set the value as

@concat(replace(item().name,'_20231026.txt',''))

This setup successfully loads data for the DESCRIPTION_CANDIDATENOTES table by removing _20231026.txt. However, it doesn't work for the other two tables because their file names do not directly match the table names after removing the suffix.
How can I modify the expression or the setup to dynamically strip the appropriate parts of the file names and correctly map them to the respective table names for all files?

If file names are in same pattern, then it will be possible to give table name dynamically, otherwise it is is not possible.

As per your source files and target table names, you can use below logic to achieve your requirement in this case.
Also, you have mentioned that your target SQL tables were already created. So, after getting the list of source file paths, use a lookup activity with SQL dataset. In the lookup activity query, give the below query.
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;


This will list out all the target table names as a JSON array.
Then use a For-Each activity and give your source file names array to the For-Each expression.
Inside For-Each, store the current file name in a string variable using set variable activity.

To use the current file name in the filter activity, you can make use of the above variable.
Next, take the Filter activity and give the below expressions to it.
Items : @activity('Lookup1').output.value
Condition : @startswith(join(skip(split(variables('curr_filename'),'_'),1),'_'), join(skip(split(item().TABLE_NAME,'_'),1),'_'))


The above filter activity will filter out the required table names by checking whether some part current file name starts with some part of the table name or not.
In each iteration, it will filter out the required table name. For sample, if the current file name is DC_RESUMEPDFs_20231026.txt, it will give the required table name in the filter activity output.

Inside For-Each, After the filter activity, you can take a copy activity with dataset parameters for both source and target datasets.
Use the below expressions for the source file name and target table name in the copy activity.
Source file name : @item().name
Target table name : @activity('Filter1').output.value[0].TABLE_NAME

In each iteration, the filter activity will give the required table name and copy activity will copy the source file to the target table.
